# How often should one open/close fstream object c++

Tags: c++, io, fstream

so the write elm and getfileID functions require the cursor pos in the file 
(write elm appends to the end, getFileID prints lines first to last)

```
    #ifndef file_operations_header
    #define file_operations_header
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    #include "First_classes_header.h"


    class fileOPerations
    {
    private:
        string line;
        fstream f_myFileOut;
    public:
        fileOPerations();

        void closeFile()
        {
            f_myFileOut.close();
        }

        int getFileID()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            if (f_myFileOut.is_open())
            {
                while(f_myFileOut.good()){
                    getline(f_myFileOut,line);
                    ++counter;
                    cout << line << endl;
                    }
            }f_myFileOut.close();
            return counter;
        }



        int writeElm(makeVector& mV,int i)
        {
            f_myFileOut.open("file.txt",ios::out|ios::app|ios::ate);
            if (f_myFileOut.is_open())
            {
                f_myFileOut << mV.str_vector[i].counter << "\t";
                f_myFileOut << mV.str_vector[i].name << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "can't open file." << endl;
            }
            return 0;
        }


        friend class makeVector;
    };

    fileOPerations::fileOPerations():f_myFileOut("file.txt",ios::out|ios::app|ios::in){}

    #endif // file_operations_header
```

and the call to getFileID in my main doesn't print anything because writeElm()
set the cursor pos to the end of the file.

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <vector>
        #include "First_classes_header.h"
        #include "file_operations.h"
        using namespace std;



        int main()
        {
            fileOPerations fpObject;
            makeVector vecObject;

            int fileID = fpObject.getFileID();

            while(true){
                IDgenerator();

                int genID = IDgenerator::GetID();
                int currentID = fileID + genID;
                string workingName = nameGetter::setName();


                vecObject.vecSetter(currentID,workingName);
                fpObject.writeElm(vecObject, currentID); // error within this function

                fpObject.getFileID();

            }fpObject.closeFile();


            return 0;

        }
```

Is it safe/effecient/effective to call f_myFileOut.open() with different parameters
in each separate function?

```
        int getFileID()
        {
            f_myFileOut.open(("file.txt",ios::out|ios::app|ios::in)

            int counter = 0;
            ...
```

...

```
    int writeElm(makeVector& mV,int i)
    {
        f_myFileOut.open("file.txt",ios::out|ios::app|ios::ate);
```

Or should I set the cursor pos manually?

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize at this stage of development your software? and ever more, why are you trying to focus so much in I/O optimization over files? that part will be slow anyway. Just make it work, and after the programs runs smooth, refactor it and start to optimize the real bottlenecks using a profiler or similar.

Answer (score 2):

While it is certainly not efficient, to open/close the same file over and over again, it would be safe, and I'd even call it better coding style, because currently you are opening a file in one method and closing it in another, and in both cases it is not obvious from the function name that this is one of their side effects (contratry to e.g. `closeFile()`). Also you are already opening/closing the file in every iteration, so this would "only" double the open/close operations.

In general however, I'd definitively recommend to open the file once at the beginning of your program, close it at the end and e.g. use `f_myFileOut.seekg (0,f_myFileOut.beg)` and `f_myFileOut.seekg (0,f_myFileOut.end)` in between, to move your iterator around.